# How can I set the icon for my Today Widget in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, widget, icons

My question is, how do I set up in my Xcode icon for my Today Widget? Maybe this is a stupid question, but I've never found an answer or manual. My application icon already has, but not the widget. Thanks for the advice.

**Solved:** I found that there is a bug, I had to remove the widget from "today" and add again and the icon now displayed ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It uses the same icon with your application. You don't have to specify addition for Today widget

If it does not appear, you can try those solutions.

- Remove your App Icon from the ImageSet and add again
- Add images to "iPhone Spotlight"

The image below shows where "App Icon Source" is.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but the widget icon is still white (default).

Comment: If you use ImageSet for "App Icon Source", try to add icon to Spotlights. For my case, I have only to add to "iPhone App iOS7,8"

Comment: I found that there is a bug, I had to remove the widget from "today" and add again and the icon now displayed ;-)

Answer (score 0):

1.Remove app when widget is enable.
2.Install your app again.
3.In Some iOS Version has a higher risk of widget icon is gone.

Do test in different Version
It is ok： iOS 8.0.2、iOS 9.0 and later

Has Problem version: iOS 8.4.1、 iOS 8.3
(maybe in 8.1.1 ~ 8.4.1 has problem)

you can do the same test in other OS vesion